# Smallest function whose inverse converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there some increasing function $f(n)$ that grows slower than $n^{c}$ for some $c > 1$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f(n)}$ converges?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, $f(n)=n(\log(n))^2$.  (Of course you can ignore the first term where the reciprocal is undefined, and the finitely many terms where it may be bigger than $n^c$ for $c$ close to $1$.)

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your title question, however, is no.  That is, given an increasing function $f(n) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum \frac{1}{f(n)}$ converges, there exists an increasing function $g(n)$ such that

- $\sum \frac{1}{g(n)}$ converges, and
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = 0$.

(Unfortunately the proof escapes me at the moment.)

Comment: Here is a reference: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2687153

Comment: It goes like this.. let $k_1 > k_2 > ...$ such that  $\sum_{n \geq k_j} {1 \over f(n)} < 3^{-j}$. Let $A_j$ be the set of $n$ with $k_j \geq n > k_{j+1}$. Then for $n \in A_j$ let $g(n) = (2/3)^j f(n)$

Comment: @Zaricuse: I guess you meant $k_1 < k_2 < \cdots$.

Comment: yeah $k_1 < k_2 < ...$ and $k_j \leq n < k_{j+1}$