# find a the following series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

this is just somthing i thought about (i dont know if there is an answer)

> Let $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \to L_1$
>
> ($a_n $ is a positive sequence)
>
> find a sequence $b_n$ such that:
>
> $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{b_n}{a_n} = \infty$
>
> and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n = L_2$ (the series converges)

if there is no solution can this be proven?

if we add the fact that $a_n$ is monotone decending would that help?

thanks alot!

Comment: I think it is more interesting if $b_n/a_n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: For $a_n/b_n$ you can take $b_n:=a_n/n^2$.

Comment: woops, corrected!

Comment: Found it. (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20378/which-series-converges-the-most-slowly) This, of course, have been answered before.

Comment: I'd recommend closing it for this reason... but not enough points yet

Answer (score 2):

**NOTICE**

This is an answer to the original question. While I was writing the answer the OP changed the condition $a_n/b_n\to\infty$ to $b_n/a_n\to\infty$.

Take $b_n=a_n^2$. Since $\sum a_n$ converges, $a_n\to0$, and $a_n/b_n=1/a_n\to\infty$. Also, $a_n$ is bounded. Let $A$ be an upper bound. Then $0\le b_b\le A\,a_n$, so that $\sum b_n$ converges.

Comment: Notice that the problem has changed. The condition $b_n/a_n\rightarrow\infty$ is the one that shows the interesting property that for every convergent series, there is one that converges slower.