# On convergent series - in the spirit of Abel and Dini

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

The following is something that I think and hope is true. I tried searching for it online but with little success. A reference, proof, or counterexample would be nice.

> Suppose $a_i $ is a positive sequence and $\sum_i a_i < \infty.$ Then there exists a positive sequence $b_i$ s.t $\sum_i b_i < \infty$ and $\sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} < \infty$.

Comment: This is true, you can take $b_n=\sqrt {\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}a_i}$.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20378/which-series-converges-the-most-slowly) or [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49415/nonexistence-of-boundary-between-convergent-and-divergent-series) for more information and some relevant links.

Comment: @lulu I saw this post - I don't think it's neceassily true that $\sum_i b_i < \infty$ if we do that

Comment: Yes....I don't see how to show that.  Indeed, it looks like it might not be hard to make a counterexample to that.  Odd.   Rubin's claim regarding that series isn't very interesting if the sum diverges (not a proof of anything, clearly)