# Rate of convergence to zero of an integrand given its integral is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Let $h(x)$ be real-valued, monotonically-decreasing function on the non-negative reals such that $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{k+1} h(x) \, dx$ is convergent for some positive integer $k$.

Does it follow that there exists $\beta > 0$ such that $h(x) = O\!\left( \frac{1}{x^{k+2+\beta}} \right)$ as $x \to \infty$?

*Remark*: Naively, $h(x)$ needs to decrease to zero sufficiently quickly to override the growth of $x^{k+1}$ ... but I'm worried about whether I've accidentally asserted the existence of a "slowest function with a converging integral" (which doesn't exist - [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9350) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20378)).

*Why I am asking*: I have a function $f(x)$ and am seeking to establish whether $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{k} f(x) \, dx$ is convergent.  I applied integration by parts to the finite integral
$$\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{t} x^{k} f(x) \, dx
  &=
  \left[
    \frac{x^{k+1} f(x)}{k+1}
    -
    \int \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} f'(x) \, dx
  \right]_{0}^{t}
  \\&=
    \frac{t^{k+1} f(t)}{k+1}
    -
    \int_{0}^{t} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} f'(x) \, dx
\end{align*}$$
From other information, I know that $f'(x)$ is monotonically decreasing, $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{k+1} f'(x) \, dx$ is convergent and $f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. (In fact in my particular application, $f'(x)$ turns out to be the tail probability of a cumulative distribution function on the non-negative reals.)
But I appear to need to know how quickly $f(t)$ tends to zero if I'm to conclude that the first term on the right-hand side has a finite limit as $t \to \infty$.  I'm hoping that this information can be deduced from the convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{k+1} f'(x) \, dx$.

(This question is a refinement of an [earlier one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4037630).  I am asking a new question [as per guidance](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23033/190548).  The condition that $h(x)$ is monotonically decreasing was added after I realized I forgot it, following comments by @user10354138.  Many thanks in advance.)

*Edit*: See this [question & answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4071584/190548) for a revised question that got to an answer that I applied.

Comment: Basically the same example defeats your attempt to bound $h$.  Just change the height to go much faster than your suggested bound but the base compensate by becoming much narrower.

Comment: If you want to get a bound like that, you need to do something to prevent the function from laying really low for a long time and infinitely often create a spike, or that changes sign sufficiently often to avoid a bound by immediately creating nearly opposite spikes (such as $\sin(x^2)$).  Something like $h$ is nonincreasing would work, but it may be too restrictive for your application?

Comment: No: consider $h(x) = 1/(x^{k+2}(\log x)^2)$. (Make it equal to $0$ for $0\le x\le1$ to avoid irrelevant problems at the integral's left endpoint.)

Answer (score 1):

(Writing out the answer as indicated by @[Greg Martin].)

Let
$$
  h(x) = \begin{cases}
    \displaystyle\frac{1}{x^{k+2}(\log x)^2} & \text{if $x \geq e$}
  \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$
Then for $x \geq e$, $h(x)$ is monotonically decreasing and
$$
  \int x^{k+1} h(x) \, dx 
  =
  \int \frac{1}{x(\log x)^2} \, dx
  \underset{y \, = \, \log x}{=}
  \int \frac{1}{y^2} \, dy
  =
  -\frac{1}{y}
  =
  -\frac{1}{\log x}
$$
so
$$
  \int_{e}^{\infty} x^{k+1} h(x) \, dx 
  =
  \left[ -\frac{1}{\log x} \right]_{e}^{\infty}
  =
  1
$$
hence $ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{k+1} h(x) \, dx $ is convergent.  But there is no $\beta > 0$ for which $\log(x) = O\!\left(\frac{1}{x^\beta}\right)$ as $x \to \infty$.